# uploadfile asp.net object - how to set the accompanying "mystery" label

Tags: c#, asp.net, text, label

I have the following object in my aspx code.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"......>
```

It renders in html like the below image after I browse to a file:

[image]

Once I press the "Upload" button to read the file into a base64 encoded string the label text "rabbit2.jpg" **dissappears**.  That mysterious label came with the uploadfile object but there does not seem to be any properties to reset it to Rabbit.jpg or "Rabbit.jpg Uploaded Successfully".

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 0):

The "mystery" label is done by the browser. It is the filename(s) of the file that has been selected by the user on their local pc. So the properties you want to use in code behind must come from the FileUpload Control.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: After "Choosing" a file and then viewing the source html I do not see any markup that displays the filename I just chose.  Nor do I see "No file chosen" which is the default label that shows up at startup.  The problem I am trying to solve is once I press the "upload" button I would like to use that same mystery label to pass the message "rabbit.jpg uploaded successfully".  How can I do that?  Thank you.

Comment: You cannot. You have to add a Label Control yourself.